# How to change references represenation

Tags: strapi

For example I got the following references in my strapi instance.

```
Product:
  id
  name: String
  ...
  categories: Array of Category

Category:
  id
  name: String
```

As you can see in the following screenshot, the strapi admin user interface shows up the categories by id. I wish to see the category names instead of the ids.

[image]

**Where do I set this option in strapi admin?**

Comment: You can click on the `configure the layout` button it will redirect you to the setting view. Then you can click on your field and set the field you want to be displayed.

Comment: I did that before for both. Product and Category. Entry title `Configure the layout -> 
Edit View (Settings) -> Entry title = name`. Its probably a strapi bug?

Comment: You need to click on the relational field and then you have a form at the bottom of the view with a select input that sets the relational's displayed field.

Comment: Thanks. That worked!